# Regex remove character in string that starts with

Tags: regex, notepad++

I try to remove a character in a string from a very large text file using Notepad++. First I need to find the string in the file.
Example string:

```
"http://cloud-3.steamusercontent.com/ugc/788631267073514368/858BBB7E3B311941C990CCFA6071FE43A5EC84AE/",
```

Now I would like to remove any "/" after the "ugc/".
So far I found the regex to get the part I want:

```
(?<=\/ugc)(.*/)(?=\")
```

This returns

```
788631267073514368/858BBB7E3B311941C990CCFA6071FE43A5EC84AE/
```

Now I struggle to remove the "/" in that string.

Comment: `i would like to replace any "/" after the "ugc/"` Replace with what?

Comment: Replace ``\`` with an empty string.

Comment: replace was wrong, i would like to remove it

Comment: Are you trying to remove the "\" directly in Notepad++ via its search and replace?

Comment: Try `(?:\G(?!^)|.*\/ugc)([^\/"]*)\/(?:".*)?` and replace with `$1`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7RuX0H/1).

Comment: it is an idea, but i don't want to delete the rest of the line. found a solution from ZygD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this may work:

[image]

**Find what:** `(.*?\/ugc\/)(.*)\/(.*?)\/(\")`
**Replace with:** `\1\2\3\4`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working!, now i have to figure out why :)

Answer (score 0):

let regExpOut = "788631267073514368/858BBB7E3B311941C990CCFA6071FE43A5EC84AE/"
regExpOut.split("/").join("")

Comment: i'm working an a simple java function for this, but i hoped this is possible with Notepad++ directly